# How do I migrate a VM from vCloud to ESXi

Tags: vmware, migration

I'm currently working on migrating some virtual machines from a vCloud environment to an ESXi. Now I believe that if I were using a full ESX with vSphere I can just export the vApp templates to OVA or OVF, and import them into ESX, but since I'm using the free ESXi this does not seem to be supported.

The only idea that I've come up with is to deploy an ESXi instance to vCloud and install the vmware converter on each instance to deploy them to that ESXi, then export and import.

I'm not an ESXi or vCloud expert so forgive me if this is a noob question, but I couldn't find an answer to this (these are separate environments).

BTW.: I have admin access to the ESXi, but I don't have admin access to the vCloud.

Comment: I think you should correct the question's title

Comment: That's crazy! Sorry about that.